# Hiding the div and li elements when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, addeventlistener

Can anyone guide me in the correct direction please? I'm stuck with checked and not checked checkboxes. What I am trying to add:

- Text in the text field & checkbox checked - hides the div element
- Text in the text field & checkbox unchecked by entry - hides the first li element
- Empty text field by entry & checkbox checked hides the second li element

What I have now:

```js
let txt = document.getElementById("name")
let but = document.getElementById("send")
let out = document.getElementById("greeting")
let divv = document.getElementById("errors")
let nameError = document.getElementById("name-error")
let consError = document.getElementById("consent-error")
let cons = document.getElementById("consent")

but.disabled = true
divv.style.display = "block"

cons.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (cons.checked && txt.value !== '') {
    consError.style.display = "none"
    but.disabled = false
  } else {
    consError.style.display = "block"
    but.disabled = true
  }
})

txt.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (txt.value !== '' && cons.checked === false) {
    but.disabled
  } else {
    but.disabled = false
  }
})

function fun() {
  out.textContent = "Hey " + txt.value + "!"
}

but.addEventListener("click", fun)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>A checkbox</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input id="name" placeholder="Name">
  <label>
      <input id="consent" type="checkbox">
      I agree
    </label>
  <input id="send" type="button" value="Submit">
  <p id="greeting"></p>
  <div id="errors" style="color: red; display: none;">
    <p>Error:</p>
    <ul>
      <li id="name-error">Please enter a name</li>
      <li id="consent-error">Please give consent</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Before I had `cons.addEventListener` like this and it was hiding the second li element but didn't keep the button disabled

```
cons.addEventListener("input", function() {
if (cons.checked){
  consError.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    consError.style.display = "block"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the validator outside to single function like this

```
function validator() {
  if (cons.checked && txt.value !== '') {
    but.disabled = false
    divv.style.display = "none"
  } else {
    but.disabled = true
    divv.style.display = "block"
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A checkbox</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <label>
        <input id="consent" type="checkbox"> I agree </label>
    <input id="send" type="button" value="Submit">
    <p id="greeting"></p>
    <div id="errors" style="color: red; display: none;">
        <p>Error:</p>
        <ul>
            <li id="name-error">Please enter a name</li>
            <li id="consent-error">Please give consent</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        let txt = document.getElementById("name")
        let but = document.getElementById("send")
        let out = document.getElementById("greeting")
        let divv = document.getElementById("errors")
        let nameError = document.getElementById("name-error")
        let consError = document.getElementById("consent-error")
        let cons = document.getElementById("consent")

        but.disabled = true
        divv.style.display = "block"

        function validator() {
            if (cons.checked && txt.value !== '') {
                but.disabled = false
                divv.style.display = "none"
            } else {
                but.disabled = true
                divv.style.display = "block"
            }
        }

        cons.addEventListener("change", function () {

            if (cons.checked) {
                consError.style.display = "none"
            } else {
                consError.style.display = "block"
            }

            validator();
        })

        txt.addEventListener("input", function () {

            if (txt.value !== '') {
                nameError.style.display = "none"
            } else {
                nameError.style.display = "block"
            }

            validator()
        })

        function fun() {
            out.textContent = "Hey " + txt.value + "!"
        }

        but.addEventListener("click", fun)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah, that was the way to go, thank you for your help!